# Python - loop through list of keywords, search number of matches in string, count final total

Tags: python, list, loops, text

I have some words I want to check and see if they occur in a research abstract and if so, count the number of occurrences.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong with my code, but it's not counting correctly. Thanks in advance!

```
 mh_terms = ['mental', 'ptsd', 'sud', 'substance abuse', 'drug abuse', 
  'alcohol', 'alcoholism', 'anxiety', 'depressing', 'bipolar', 'mh', 
  'smi', 'oud', 'opioid' ]

  singleabstract = 'This is a research abstract that includes words like 
  mental health and anxiety.  My hope is that I get my code to work and 
  not resort to alcohol.'

  for mh in mh_terms: 
       mh = mh.lower
       mh = str(mh)
       number_of_occurences = 0
       for word in singleabstract.split():
          if mh in word:
          number_of_occurences += 1
  print(number_of_occurences)
```

Comment: But you want a counter occurency per each word? Can you post a minimal desired output? Also you are checking substring occurencies

Comment: This looks like you need help on how to debug, no clear programming question. I suggest you 1) research how to debug, e.g. `pdb.set_trace()` or at least log output as you go 2) if you're still stuck, at least share the error message you're receiving.

Btw `mh = mh.lower` is not what you want. You're assigning a method/function to a variable and then treating it like a string. Pretty sure you want `mh = mh.lower()`.

Comment: Well you are printing number of occurrences outside of the first for loop so it will only print for the last word.  Try doing that print at the end of the first loop.

Comment: Wonka - the desired output would be a count of 3 since the words "mental", "anxiety" and "alcohol" occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, for grouping, a `dict` is a good way to go. For counting, you can use an implementation like the following:

```py
c = {}

singleabstract = 'This is a research abstract that includes words like 
  mental health and anxiety.  My hope is that I get my code to work and 
  not resort to alcohol.'

for s in singleabstract.split():
    s = ''.join(char for char in s.lower() if char.isalpha()) # '<punctuation>'.isalpha() yields False
    # you'll need to check if the word is in the dict
    # first, and set it to 1
    if s not in c:
        c[s] = 1
    # otherwise, increment the existing value by 1
    else:
        c[s] += 1

# You can sum the number of occurrences, but you'll need
# to use c.get to avoid KeyErrors
occurrences = sum(c.get(term, 0) for term in mh_terms)

occurrences
3

# or you can use an if in the generator expression
occurrences = sum(c[term] for term in mh_terms if term in c)
```

The most optimal way of counting occurrences is using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). This is a dictionary, which allows you O(1) checking of keys:

```py
from collections import Counter

singleabstract = 'This is a research abstract that includes words like 
  mental health and anxiety.  My hope is that I get my code to work and 
  not resort to alcohol.'

# the Counter can consume a generator expression analogous to
# the for loop in the dict implementation
c = Counter(''.join(char for char in s.lower() if char.isalpha()) 
            for s in singleabstract.split())

# Then you can iterate through
for term in mh_terms:
    # don't need to use get, as Counter will return 0
    # for missing keys, rather than raising KeyError 
    print(term, c[term]) 

mental 1
ptsd 0
sud 0
substance abuse 0
drug abuse 0
alcohol 1
alcoholism 0
anxiety 1
depressing 0
bipolar 0
mh 0
smi 0
oud 0
opioid 0
```

To get your desired output, you can sum up the values for the `Counter` object:

```py
total_occurrences = sum(c[v] for v in mh_terms)

total_occurrences
3
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, `print(number_of_occurences)` should be scoped for every `mh` to print the occurrences for that particular word. Second, print the word part of the our print message. I think main issue with your program is that you should use  `mh.lower()` instead of `mh.lower`